# SQL Server: how to execute TOP before Count in a single query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to sort through my `fn_dblog`. I want to get a percent ratio on how often each operation type is being executed.

The data is way too big to run a count on the entire dataset.

In one query, how to I get the top 1,000,000 rows, and then count the number of times each type of Operation appears?

Comment: What is "way too big" to count?  Just curious if we're talking millions or billions or more.

Comment: @PaulWilliams -- it seems unlikely that it is way to big to count since I count many things all the time in SQL -- kinda what sql is intended to do.

Comment: my .ldf file is approaching 2TB of data, which is what's prompting this investigation, It's a live database too so I can't tax the server for more than a few minutes without causing problems on the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems simple...

```
     SELECT COUNT(bar)
     FROM (
        SELECT TOP 1000000 *
        FROM FOO
     ) AS SUBQUERYRESULT
     GROUP BY bar
```

Comment: sorry, was that me?

anyways, I can get these to work on a dummy table

 "SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM Foo;"

 "SELECT COUNT (Bar) FROM Foo GROUP BY Bar;"

But not any combination

Comment: @Zeckal -- ok I changed my example to use your name... is this clearer now?

Comment: When I query with "SELECT COUNT(bar) FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM foo) AS SUBQUERYRESULT"
I just get a count of 1000, not the different counts for each value of bar

Comment: AH! there it is, alias AND group by clause, has worked on my real table, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a sub-select of the number of rows you want and then count grouped on the Operation column:

```
select Operation, count(*) as OpCount
from
(
    select top 1000000 Operation
    from MyTable
) a
group by Operation
```